# My Maya texture does not render at all in Open GL!

Tags: opengl, textures

I uploaded my layered Maya (Maya 2012) Textures via objLoader into my opengl project. I also uploaded 3D textured model. I am able to render a model but not even one texture is showing.
Before pasting any code here, i thought maybe there is some common mistake that we beginners are doing, regarding this issue!?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Game Development, please show us at least some code to make sure we can help you by doing our best for it.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying vertex and colors from and imported model is always a snap but showing a texture has many factors involved with it. You might not solve this problem in one day, but there is hope.

I'm going to suggest you UV map your texture properly, avoid using any layers or what not. Maybe your application doesn't support multitexture. So, UV mapping is the simplest way to do things. Then try it out to see if it works.

I'm certain your model loader supports UV mapping.